# How to predict hour-by-hour volume if the whole day volume and hour-by-hour data is given.

Tags: probability

Assume on a future Monday the total volume of a hospital is known as $X$. What we know as well is the arrival timestamps on a large number of Mondays in the past, like $N$ timestamps each of which represents the time of arrival of a patient.

I want to predict on this future Monday, how many patients will show up per hour, like 8am-9am, 9am-10am, etc. The methodology I am using now is just to count the frequency per hour in the past data. For example, $N_1$ timestamps out of $N$ are between 8am-9am, then the predicted volume between 8am to 9am is just $N_1/N * X$.

Any better way to tackle this problem? Build a continuous distribution? Thanks

Comment: Well, why not use the average breakdowns for Monday (assuming you have them)?  Maybe the data from other days is predictive and maybe it isn't, hard to tell with no data.  As to modeling with some continuous distribution or other, you can try to fit standard distributions to the data you have and see if any model works.  A priori it seems hard to predict.

Comment: Should note:  modeling data is not easy, in general.  Here, for instance, I would expect there to be patterns in the data which should be taken into account.  Seasonality, say.  Are Hospital admissions the same in hot months as in cold?   Those factors tend to argue against taking a simple average as your sole predictor.

Comment: Sorry but what are average breakdowns? For continuous distribution, did you mean I should try some typical distributions like Gaussian, Exponential, etc to see which one fits the data?

Comment: I simply meant:  use the hourly breakdowns for Monday's alone, if you have that.  I have no idea if all days of the week are statistically the same for your purposes or not, but I wouldn't automatically assume they were.  For your other question, yes.  Pick a model, however you choose, parameterize it appropriately and then see if what you get fits your data or not.